# How do I pass this object to another Object and access its variables using a friend class (c++)

Tags: c++

So I have searched high and low and maybe I don't know what question I'm trying to ask, and if that's the case please help me figure out what that might be.

I am trying to print out the color of myCar object from the car class, using a function from the myMan object from the man class. I (think) I have the man class as a friend to the car class so I dont know why I cant access the cars private color variable. Can someone tell me why I can't access the cars private color variable? I have to use friend.

I have been trying to do this for more then 20 hours now and I'm at my wits end.I have included all the files I have because I have seen it done other ways (all in one file) and can't seem to reproduce it broken up like this.

Error   1   error C2433: 'man' : 'friend' not permitted on data declarations **car.h**  line 14

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   **car.h**   line 14

Error   3   error C2248: 'car::color' : cannot access private member declared in class 'car'    **man.cpp**  line   13

Error   4   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'car' **man.h** line 16

Error   5   error C2660: 'man::printCarColor' : function does not take 1 arguments  **source.cpp** line 16

Error   6   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'car'    **man.h**   line 16

car.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "man.h"
using namespace std;

class car
{
public:

    car();
    car(string);
    ~car();
    friend man;
private:
    string color;

};
```

car.cpp

```
#include "car.h"


car::car()
{
}
car::car(string c){
    color = c;
}

car::~car()
{
}
```

man.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "car.h"

using namespace std;


class man
{
public:
    string name;
    man();
    man(string);
    void printCarColor(car);
    ~man();
};
```

man.cpp

```
#include "man.h"


man::man()
{
}
man::man(string newname)
{
    name = newname;
}

void man::printCarColor(car mycar){
    cout << mycar.color;
}

man::~man()
{
}
```

source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "car.h"
#include "man.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    car myCar("green");
    //cout << myCar.color;

    man myMan("Jim");
    myMan.name;
    myMan.printCarColor(myCar);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a circular include dependency. car.h includes man.h and man.h includes car.h. This cannot work. Remove `#include "man.h"` from car.h, use `friend class man` instead of `friend man`.

Comment: FYI, `man.h` includes `car.h` and `car.h` includes `man.h` which is a circular include dependency. **However**, why do you want to use a friend anyway? I would say in _most_ cases you would want to avoid friends. Why not just add `const std::string& getColor() const;` to the `car` class?

Edit: Using friends breaks encapsulation and breaking encapsulation should come with a very good justification...

Comment: I am using friend becuse Im trying to learn how as it is needed for a larger assignment, so I broke it down into something smaller to learn how its used first. I don't post on here often at all, can I mark this as solved somehow? edit: found it

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular include dependency. car.h includes man.h and man.h includes car.h. This cannot work. Remove #include "man.h" from car.h, use friend class man instead of friend man. –  n.m.

** hope this isn't a bad way of answer this, credit goes to ^

Comment: It is fine to answer your own question citing the comments that helped you. But you could have written it as a better answer for example giving the implementation you choosed - but I do not think that deserved a -1 :-)